# Facebook it's not reading any meta tag from Head on my React Web App

Tags: html, reactjs, metadata, facebook-opengraph, head

Here is my code from the Head. I checked on https://validator.w3.org/ and it's ok. Facebook it's not reading almost any from the head. Not a single meta for example. Meanwhile google it's reading all the Head, I check the web with https://search.google.com/test/rich-results

Any Idea?  thanks !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset=UTF-8>
  <meta name="keywords" content="Menús digitales, carta digital, tu web digital, ofrece tus productos, carta digital de servicios y productos. Myqmp, kmepdido, quemepido. Servicio digital para negocios, restaurantes, comercios. Comercio digital, ecommerce. " >
  <link href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lmyapp.appspot.com/o/logo-face.jpg?alt=media&token=a58ec397-77dc-4e6c-9998-87779-88776" rel="image_src">

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://myapp.com">
  
  <title>My App</title>
   <meta property='og:title' content='MyApp'>
   <meta property='og:description' content='MyApp es un motor web que permite crear rápidamente tu web.' >
   <meta property='og:type' content='website' >
   <meta property='og:url' content='https://myapp.com/' >
   <meta property='og:image' content='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/14oppb7.appspot.com/o/logo-face.jpg?alt=media&token=a598ec397-77dc-4e6c-8003-9898986' >

    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <link rel="icon" href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/899pp3bb7.appspot.com/o/landing%2Fico-myapp.ico?alt=media&token=cff43pppppp2-e578ppf4bc" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" >
    <meta
      name="MyApp es un motor web. Crea rápidamente tu web y ofrece tus servicios digitales."
      content="Powered by  MyApp, Crea rápidamente tu web y ofrece tus servicios digitales. Microsites para webs en español. Menús digitales."
    >
   
    <!-- WEB FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,400i,700,700i&display=swap' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
   
  </head>
```

Comment: If your meta tags are not on the html served directly from the server some social media sites won't wait for React to generate them client side (or won't run the JavaScript at all) and will see no meta tags. I can't find any concrete "The crawler doesn't run JavaScript" on the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler) but it does make it sound like it only downloads the first 1Mb of your content then ignores the rest, which would mean it most likely doesn't run any scripts.

Comment: Use dynamic rendering instead, but you will need a server to render `head meta` and serves it to facebook crawler.

Comment: I deployed the App on Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

There is this page on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Copy the URL of your website into the form there and press return. This takes you to a page where you see what Facebook "knows" about that website (it knows much more, but well). Press the button "Scrape again" (or similar). This should fix your problem if all the og meta tags are correct.

Comment: This is what Facebook sees, nothing else:    
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="https://c.staticblitz.com/d/webcontainer.1fe307dfa45b7c0db52d14a83855a3415d9b0c82.js"></script><script src="/vendor.bundle.js?1606335043770"></script><script src="/app.bundle.js?1606335043770"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

Finally it's reading the dynamic Head info from my App.

Here is the solution: just wait, and in a few days Facebook will see all the content.